# Selenium chrome driver .click() does not work on particolar website Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, callback

i am trying to log in in a particular website , i fill out email and password and then i click on "login " , but actually it does not login but it redirects me to the home page, i studied the situation and noticed that some websites has a "callback" function, that you can find trought console ,in fact , when i have to register (no login, but sign up) it asks me for captcha, and trought console i found that captcha has a call back function that - if called - it simulates the " register now " button (i easly found this function trought a script that find callback linked to captcha ).
the point is : how can i find this callback function in case of login that has no captcha ? i dont know how to start, any suggestions or guide to study? thats my simply script by the way

```
    driver.get("https://www.streetmachine.com/login")
    time.sleep(1)
    el=driver.find_element_by_name("email")
    el.send_keys(lf[0])
    el=driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    el.send_keys(lf[1])
    
    time.sleep(3)
    el=driver.find_element_by_id("login-form-submit")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", el)
```

as you can see the website is the one called in get() , thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the "ActionChains"; find the element first and then perform the click.

For example as the following code:

```
    def click_login_button(self, **kargs):
        try:
           button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(
            lambda x: x.find_element_by_id("login-form-submit")
           )
        except TimeoutException:
           pass
        if not button.is_enabled():
           pass
        webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

Reference:

Mouse actions in detail, https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/mouse_and_keyboard_actions_in_detail/